# Displaying parameters inside SSRS header

Tags: reporting-services

So I'd like to display selected parameter values inside SSRS report header.

My parameter, let's call it STATUS, is defined as follows::

- Allow Multiple Values checked
- Data Type: TEXT
- Available values: pulled from the database through a stored procedure. Value field is ID and Label field is NAME.

I added a textbox inside report header and specified it's expression as follows:

=Join(Parameters!STATUS.Label,", ")

Everything works fine except for I see selected IDs and not NAMES listed.
For example, I see: 1,2,5 instead of Active, Inactive, Pending... etc.

Available parameter options (inside the control from which parameter can be specified) are displayed correctly (NAMEs are displayed and not IDs)

Is this a SSRS bug?

Comment: This should work as you expect. I've just tested on SSRS2016 and it worked perfectly. What version of SSRS are you using? I created 2 textboxes, one showing IDs and one showing labels, both did what I expected. If you still have issues, post the build number of SQL Server/SSRS

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that something went awry between the Visual Studio UI and the XML code in the background. You can try View Code and search for "STATUS.Label" to see if the XML references the ID, or you can delete the parameter and re-create it.